# Fedora Linux Disk Usage Analyzer falsely reports root at 100% full

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, fedora, disk-space, fedora-16

I've got a box setup with Fedora 16 that I'm currently using for a small home server.

I was having some issues with samba sharing when I ran the disk usage analyzer and found that while I have a total of 5.9TB of total space (including external media disks) and only 853GB are being used, the root folder is still being reported as 100% full. It shows that the external media is taking up the majority of space.

[image: disk usage analyzer falsely reports root as 100% full fedora linux]

I'm trying use the 3TB WD My Book for backups using Deja Dup, but anytime I try a backup, it throws and error saying I do not have enough disk space, which is not true, as less than 400GB worth of files are being backed up and the disk properties window reports that there are 2.8TB of space still free on the drive, which seems to contradict the disk usage analyzer's calculation of that drive being 60% full.

[image]

I've recently moved a lot of files around between the external and internal drives in order to reformat them and organize them into proper samba shares. I've emptied the trash and deleted trash folders off of the external drives. I've also run yum clean all. I've also got another problem where an iMac on the network can connect to the shares but cannot open them with an error that the files are in use by another user on the network, and I'm wondering if this problem with the disk usage is related or even causing that problem.

I've looked around on google and a somewhat common culprit identified as causing this problem has to do with inodes, but I'm not sure what that is or how to fix it.

[This Question](https://superuser.com/questions/42955/how-can-a-linux-disk-be-full-but-files-total-to-significanly-less) may be similar to my problem, but he does not elaborate on his answer very well.

Output of the df -h command as requested:

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                 50G  4.9G   45G  10% /
devtmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 1.7G  560K  1.7G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg_tangentserver-lv_root   50G  4.9G   45G  10% /
tmpfs                                 1.7G   42M  1.6G   3% /run
tmpfs                                 1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                 1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /media
/dev/sdd2                             497M   95M  378M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_tangentserver-lv_home  243G  229G  1.6G 100% /home
/dev/sdb1                             466G   27M  466G   1% /media/VERBATIM
/dev/sdc1                             917G   88G  783G  11% /media/SEAGATE
/dev/sde1                             2.8T  391G  2.4T  14% /media/WD My Book
/dev/sdk1                             917G  136G  736G  16% /media/LACIE
/dev/sda1                             147G  147M  140G   1% /media/MAXTOR
```

Comment: Can you post a `df -h` from a terminal?

Comment: output added to the question